# Â character before a pound sign in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am inserting data into a MySQL Table using PHP/SQL Queries and when i use a `£` (pound) symbol its inserting a `Â` character before so it looks like

```
Â£ then the rest of the string
```

My SQL Query is just simple:

```
$sql="INSERT into table (column1, column2) values (value1, value2)";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

is there any way i can stop the `Â` from inserting into the MySQL table?

Thanks

Comment: what is the collation type of the field? Moreover, make sure your string stores the pound sign in proper format. It's also a good practice to make your headers utf-8 by adding this to the top of your php file: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Try to trim the values before using it in the insert query.